# Typescript / Javascript object properties seem to disapear when accessing them?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, typescript, javascript-objects

I have the following code :

```
function generateImageURLS(product : Product) : Array<string>{
console.log(product);
console.log(product["price"]);
console.log(product.price);
```

When i debug my project in google chrome and I open up the first output I can see all properties are set and everthing seems normal...

but when I want to print any property of my object alone a always get

```
undefinded
```

which then causes errors in the rest of the programm.

How does this happen and what can I do to prevent it?

Comment: Can you show us what `Product` is ?

Comment: Can you show us the output of the object properties in the console?

Comment: How do you try to *"print any property"*? And can you include the Errors you get?

Comment: My Object [link](https://imgur.com/a/nNt4N) - pretty large Object from a Web-API

Comment: @D.Simon https://imgur.com/GuLUJwc

Comment: All the information is bundled in another `product` object. So to get the price, you need this: `product.product.price`.